# Merging census tract data to zip codes using area weights

Tags: r

I would like to merge data that has been summarized at the census tract level to zipcodes (zcta5).  Each zcta5 contains multiple census tracts and the percent area weights are given.  The data structure is a follows:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ZCTA5 = c(98110L, 98110L, 98110L, 98110L, 98310L, 
98310L, 98310L, 98310L, 98310L, 98310L, 98310L), ctfips = c(53035090700, 
53035090800, 53035090900, 53035091000, 53035080101, 53035080102, 
53035080200, 53035080300, 53035080400, 53035091800, 53035091900
), ZAREAPCT = c(22.08, 27.38, 10.39, 40.15, 11.34, 11.88, 11.13, 
8.39, 29.96, 15.77, 11.53)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))



ZCTA5        ctfips ZAREAPCT
 <int>        <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 98110 53035090700.    22.1 
 2 98110 53035090800.    27.4 
 3 98110 53035090900.    10.4 
 4 98110 53035091000.    40.2 
 5 98310 53035080101.    11.3 
 6 98310 53035080102.    11.9 
 7 98310 53035080200.    11.1 
 8 98310 53035080300.    8.39
 9 98310 53035080400.    30.0 
10 98310 53035091800.    15.8 
11 98310 53035091900.    11.5 

df2 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(13149, 13149, 13149, 13149, 
13149, 13149, 13149, 13149, 13149, 13149, 13149), class = "Date"), 
ctfips = c(53035080101, 53035080102, 53035080200, 53035080300, 
3035080400, 53035090700, 53035090800, 53035090900, 53035091000, 
53035091800, 53035091900), DS_PM_pred = c(5.293963, 5.25517, 
5.289735, 5.318018, 5.245346, 5.071309, 5.170838, 5.099778, 
5.181464, 5.202728, 5.23456)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "ctfips", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
ctfips = c(53035080101, 53035080102, 53035080200, 53035080300, 
53035080400, 53035090700, 53035090800, 53035090900, 53035091000, 
53035091800, 53035091900)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame", vars = "ctfips", drop = TRUE))

date             ctfips DS_PM_pred
<date>            <dbl>      <dbl>
1 2006-01-01 53035080101.       5.29
2 2006-01-01 53035080102.       5.26
3 2006-01-01 53035080200.       5.29
4 2006-01-01 53035080300.       5.32
5 2006-01-01 53035080400.       5.25
6 2006-01-01 53035090700.       5.07
7 2006-01-01 53035090800.       5.17
8 2006-01-01 53035090900.       5.10
9 2006-01-01 53035091000.       5.18
10 2006-01-01 53035091800.       5.20
11 2006-01-01 53035091900.       5.23
```

Examining df1, each zipcode ZCTA5 overlaps with multiple census tracts (ctfips) and the area weight percentages are ZAREAPCT.  In this example there are two unique ZCTA5s (98110 & 98310).  The first contains 4 census tracts and the second has 7.

df2 contains each census tract (ctfips) and the variable I would like to aggregate to the ZCTA5s. (DS_DM_Pred).

The output I am looking for would look like this:

```
ZCTA5  date         DS_DM_Pred_weighted
98110  2006-01-01   5.14981
98310  2006-01-01   5.250558
```

where the weighted average computed over census tracts in each ZCTA5 is:
5.14 = 5.07*(0.221) + 5.17*(0.274) + 5.10*(0.10)4 + 5.18*(0.402)

I can't seem to wrap my head around the best way to approach this efficiently.

Comment: I am getting error with your code for `df2`. Can you confirm it's correct?

Comment: I have updated df2.  I believe it should work now.  I just tried your simple code and it DOES give the expected results.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got error with your `dput` code for `df2` but here's code that might put you on the right track -

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = "ctfips") %>%
  group_by(ZCTA5, date) %>%
  summarise(DS_DM_Pred_weighted = weighted.mean(DS_PM_pred, ZAREAPCT/100))
```